# Azure Virtual Machines(ARM) | Application Gateway | Private ip | DNS

Tags: azure, dns, ip, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Internal application gateway configured in Azure. There is one virtual machine in the back end pool of application gateway which hosts the application. That is accessible via Intranet only.

I want the IP address of my internal application gateway to be associated to a domain name for my website?? How can i achieve this?

Comment: so it doesn't have a public IP?

Comment: Do you read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal#add-an-a-record-for-your-custom-domain)?

Comment: Nope it doesn't have a public ip. i want the domain name to be attached to private ip only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a domain name, that means the application gateway needs to have a public IP address. In the gateway settings in the Azure portal, you can add a public IP address to the frontend configuration.

Looks like you already managed to put the backend of the gateway on the virtual network, that's good.

Next, you want to create a listener on the ports you need, for example 80 or 443. This is also done on the gateway configuration in the portal.

Finally, to use a domain name, you need to take the public IP address and put it in an A-record for the domain name. This would probably be in a config page with your service provider.

Comment: its an internal application gateway. We cant have a public IP in this.

Comment: Ok. Then do you mean a domain name that only resolves on your internal network? Or should it be publicly accessible on the internet?

Comment: It should resolve only in internal network. No, Public access required.

Comment: One way is to update the host name file for every machine but that not a feasible solution for 1000 users.

Comment: It all depends where these 1000 users and their machines get their DNS. - If they are joined to a domain, you can easily manage this centrally. -If they are in an Azure vnet, you can use [Azure DNS records](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/module/azurerm.dns/add-azurermdnsrecordconfig?view=azurermps-3.7.0).
- If they are not managed centrally, you could maybe add a DNS entry in the network gateway or router, but if not, you probably need to go with the hosts file...